# System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.Navigate is throwing invalidoperationexception

Tags: windows-phone-7

```
Frame    Image             Function                                                Offset    
0        coredll.dll       xxx_RaiseException                                      19        
1        mscoree3_7.dll                                                            436488    
2        mscoree3_7.dll                                                            386545    
3        mscoree3_7.dll                                                            540936    
4                          TransitionStub                                          0         
5                          System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.Navigate    1652      
6                          XXX.Components.pushScreen        172       
7                          XXX.pushHomeScr                                 996       
8                          XXX.update                                      1488      
9                          .__c__DisplayClass3._ResponseReady_b__0                 700       
10       mscoree3_7.dll                                                            429164    
11       mscoree3_7.dll                                                            185803    
12       mscoree3_7.dll                                                            184423    
13                         System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke      112       
14                         System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke      1556      
15                         System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke                     104       
16                         System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne                        476       
17                         System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl              84        
18                         System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke     80        
19                         System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch            404
```

I am using the following code to push new page

```
Uri navigateUritemp = new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
if(scrObj.NavigationService.CurrentSource != navigateUritemp)
{
scrObj.NavigationService.Navigate(navigateUritemp);
}
```

It looks the following line is throwing invalidoperationexception

```
scrObj.NavigationService.Navigate(navigateUritemp);
```

can someone tell what is wrong in this code?

Comment: got stack trace from app hub which says scrObj.NavigationService.Navigate(navigateUritemp); is throwing invalidoperationexception. I am trying to find the flow in which this exception is thrown. navigateUritemp is URI which contains correct string eg:homescreen/HomeScreen.xaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One common situation in which I've seen this `InvalidOperationException` happen is if multiple navigations are attempted simultaneously, or if a navigation attempt occurs while the app is not in the foreground.

This can happen, for example, if a user manages to hit an appbar button a second time while a slow navigation is occurring.

A quick search reveals others have seen the same sort of thing - e.g. http://www.nickharris.net/2011/01/windows-phone-7-navigation-is-not-allowed-when-the-task-is-not-in-the-foreground/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `if (scrObj.NavigationService.CurrentSource.equals(navigateUritemp))` Maybe this will help. Are you getting this exception all the time?

Comment: not even one time i got this exception. i got the stack trace which i posted above from APP HUB. it looks scrObj.NavigationService.Navigate(navigateUritemp); will throw exception when navigateUritemp is null. But in the code it will not be null at any point :(

Comment: Try to debug it. Put a breakpoint before this operations and check whether everything works. I mean all the assignments.

Comment: i have only two scenario for both i am sending valid strings. "/XXX/login/MultipleDomain.xaml" and "/XXX/homescreen/HomeScreen.xaml?membername=" + membername + "&memberid=" + memberid. Here membername and memberid are strings. Even if i send null for this params i am not getting the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following:

1. Create a new project and remove the rest of your code and keep the code related to NavigationService.
2. Crate a folder (Name the folder something like homescreen)
3. Add 2 XAML pages (eg: Page1.xaml, Page2.xaml)
4. Test NavigationService code from MainPage.xaml


   **Try this:**

   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/homescreen/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

   **or**

   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/homescreen/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

if you are using UriKind.Relative make sure to specify the correct path, eg: if you use "homescreen/Page2.xaml" it want work, you have to use "/homescreen/Page2.xaml", " / " at the beginning of your path is like "root" or "~" in ASP.NET

Comment: i am sending valid strings as parameter for Uri. If string is going to be invalid then i should get exception. i didn't get exception even once. But some user's has got it seems. Is there any possibility that Uri can become invalid at some point? i hard-coded as "NavigationService.Navigate(null, UriKind.Relative))" here i got exactly the same stack trace what i posted above

Comment: ok try to hard-coded as "NavigationService.Navigate("/folder/page.xaml", UriKind.Relative))" and see if the NavigationService work fine this mean your code is fine and you have to look in another place in your code. as I understand the destination page is null or dose not exist. are you using MVVM architectural pattern?